# DataRelation Excepción con Windows Forms ADO .Net

Tags: c#, ado.net

he comenzado a aprender las relaciones de tablas mediante las **DataRelation** y me acabo de encontrar con una excepción,que a priori se lo  que significa lo que no tengo claro es como resolverla,para ponerles en situación y que tengáis la mayor información posible os detallare a continuación cada parte de el código que interviene para que entendáis el objetivo de el código con la mayor presicion posible.

El objetivo de la aplicación es que mediante el uso de Windows Forms tengo 2 **DataGridViews** y 2 tablas en la base de datos que están relacionadas,llamadas **Pruebas** y **Medallas** el objetivo es que seleccionando una prueba en concreto del **DataGridView** se carguen en el otro **DataGridView** las **Medallas** relacionadas con dicha **Prueba**.

---

### Tablas de la Base De Datos

```
/*TABLA PRUEBAS*/ 
CREATE TABLE Pruebas(
codPrueba CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
nombrePrueba VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
nombreDeporte VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
);

/*TABLA MEDALLAS*/ 
 CREATE TABLE Medallas(
 codDeportista INT  NOT NULL,
 codPrueba CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
 fechaMedalla DATE NOT NULL,
 puestoDeportista CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL   
);
```

---

A continuación una imagen para explicar como funciona la aplicación.

[image: Imagen de la aplicacion]

Como les comento la idea es seleccionar una prueba y que aparezcan las medallas relacionadas.

A continuación les muestro los métodos que tengo dentro de mi clase Controlador.

```
 public DataSet cargarPruebas()
        {

            string consulta = "select * FROM Pruebas";
            interno = new SqlDataAdapter(consulta, conexion.Con);
            interno.Fill(ds, "Pruebas");

            string consultaEjemplares = "select * FROM Medallas";
            interno2 = new SqlDataAdapter(consultaEjemplares, conexion.Con);
            interno2.Fill(ds, "Medallas");


            return ds;
        }
```

Como se puede apreciar devuelvo un **DataSet** y ya trabajo con el **DataTable** que me interesa.

---

En el método **Load** del formulario es donde intento hacer las relaciones de ambas tablas de la siguiente manera.

```
private void Practica3Form_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    DataColumn columnaPrimaria = 
    controlador.cargarPruebas().Tables["Pruebas"].Columns["codPrueba"];
    DataColumn columnaSecun = 
    controlador.cargarPruebas().Tables["Medallas"].Columns["codPrueba"];

    =controlador.cargarPruebas().Tables["Pruebas"].DefaultView;
    pruebasGrid.DataSource = dv;

    DataRelation relacion = new 
    DataRelation("pruebasMedallas",columnaPrimaria,columnaSecun);
    controlador.cargarPruebas().Relations.Add(relacion);

}
```

---

En el **evento** de que se dispar al hacer Clic en la **Celda**

```
    private void pruebasGrid_CellContentClick(object sender, 
    DataGridViewCellEventArgs e){

    DataView tableView = new DataView();
    DataRowView dataRowView;
    tableView = new 
    DataView(controlador.cargarPruebas().Tables["pruebas"]);
    dataRowView = tableView[pruebasGrid.CurrentRow.Index];
    medallasGrid.DataSource = 
    dataRowView.CreateChildView("pruebasMedallas");


    }
```

---

Finalmente cuando cuando trato de **ejecutar** el programa me da una excepción como la que muestro a continuación.

[image: Excepción]

Agradecerle de ante mano cualquier consejo o ayuda recibida por la comunidad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una de las sobrecargas del datarelation tiene un 4to parámetro que es un true o false ese parámetro especifica si los valores pueden quedar exentos de relación 
seria a así

```
relacion = new datarelation("nombre_relacion",padre,hijo,true);
```